# Time limit for editing chat

Tags: support, chat

I have noticed that sometimes I can edit my own messages on chat, but when I view older messages I can't edit them. Is there some sort of time-limit for editing your own message? How long is this limit?

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2013, you can remove or edit your own messages until after two minutes of it being posted. After this period, editions are locked for the user.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/conversation/testing-time-limit-for-editing-chat-messages

Comment: See also: [Can we have more than 2 minutes to edit comments in chat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100682)